# can we implement IP load balancing by LVS direct routing without using VIP? is we can, How?

Tags: routing, load-balancing, lvs, virtual-ip

I am trying to implement IP Load Balancing using LVS Direct routing method. Now Ideally there is a virtual IP assigned to the Load Balancer server, but I have only 3 IP addresses.

I am using
10.209.104.6 for Load balancer node
10.209.104.5 and 10.209.104.7 for two real servers.

Comment: Please don't censor your posts needlessly. RFC1918 addresses do not need to be obscured.

Comment: @EEAA updated the IP addresses.

Comment: Why don't you get (or just use) another IP address ?

Comment: @istheEnglishway actually, i don't have one. In anyways, can we do it? i mean, if we could that would be better..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any benefit from saving one private IPv4 address (unless you ran out of private IPs like using very tight subnet which is difficult to modify), but it seems to be possible using 3 IPs for one load balancer and 2 real servers.

As stated in the [documentation](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/VS-DRouting.html), you need to assign VIP to load balancer in addition to real servers (real servers should not respond to ARP requests). The remaining two IPs are assigned to the two real servers.

The client traffic destined to VIP is directed from router/gateway to load balancer (respond to ARP) and then directed to real servers are configured.

You should consider using another load balancer to eliminate single point of failure.

Comment: thank you. Yes, I have gone through the documentation, they have used one VIP address. But I was qurious about, if we could, that is why I asked the question.